# 414 (request-uri too long) in ASP .NET MVC only on devices - 51 Degrees Device Detection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, 51degrees

I am relying on `@Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` to differentiate the visitors to an ASP .NET MVC website.

I am using `51 Degrees` library. However when browsing some images from mobile devices, I have the error `414 (request-uri too long)`. On the PC, this is not happening, only on the mobile.

The stack is showing `PathTooLongException` at :

```
   à System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
   à System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   à System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   à System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
   à System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   à System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   à System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   à System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path)
   à System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
   à System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
   à FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.Feature.ImageOptimiser.OptimisedImageResponse(HttpContext context)
   à FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule.OnPostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   à System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

It seems `FiftyOne` is in this stack. And when I uninstall 51Degrees, it resumes working. However I need 51Degrees to keep `IsMobileDevice` compatible with the current devices.

Is there any parameter I am missing ? 51degrees is version `.NET 3.1.9.3`

Comment: Seems like the `ImageOptimiser.OptimisedImageResponse` is attempting to map a virtual path to a physical disk path. The max length of a full file path is only 260 characters. My guess would be the library has managed to create a path that is just too long for the system to deal with.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue just a few days ago. We have been using the 51Degrees solution for a number of years but are just now running into the 414 issue on mobile devices.

I ended up using "[The official WURFL API for .NET](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotnet_index.php)". Easy to implement and provides all the functionality we need to read from the WURFL data repository. And now I no longer get the 414 errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever find yourself in similar situation, you can:

1. Go to **51Degrees.config** file
2. Open it
3. Scroll down until you find **imageOptimisation** section
4. Set **enabled** to **false**
5. Save and restart application

Just another way to solve the 414 issue.